# Uso del pretérito perfecto simple en Hispanoamérica

Tags: verbos, hispanoamérica, pretérito, pretérito-perfecto

¿Considera erróneo la RAE el uso del pretérito perfecto simple en contextos en los que un español utilizaría el pretérito perfecto compuesto?

Por ejemplo, un español (excepto tal vez uno de Galicia, Asturias, o las Islas Canarias) diría:

> Hoy **he visitado** a mi madre.

Mientras que el hispanoamericano promedio diría:

> Hoy **visité** a mi madre.

¿Esta última oración es un error o una variante regional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La RAE ha indicado en varios lugares que los dos usos son igualmente aceptables. Por ejemplo, en su cuenta de Twitter [afirma](https://twitter.com/jesusliragarzon/status/1290840831063203840):

[image: ¿que tiempo es más correcto utilizar: lo he visto o lo vi? Los dos usos son validos. El pretérito perfecto compuesto es más habitual es gran parte de España, mientras que el pretérito perfecto simple se emplea con mayor frecuencia en gran parte de América y algunas zonas de España para expresar acciones recientes.]

> Pregunta: ¿qué tiempo es más correcto utilizar: "Lo he visto" o "lo vi"?
>
> Respuesta: #RAEconsultas Los dos usos son válidos. El pretérito perfecto compuesto es más habitual en gran parte de España, mientras que el pretérito perfecto simple se emplea con mayor frecuencia en gran parte de América y algunas zonas de España para expresar acciones recientes.

De todos modos, aunque la Academia lo considerara erróneo yo no le haría mucho caso, ya que cuando un fenomeno lingüístico llega a extenderse por una región y a arraigar en varias comunidades de hablantes, es tan legítimo como cualquier otro. La única diferencia es que el profe te eche un rapapolvo.